# How to get who causes PostBack?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, html

In my page there are many controls and I want to know who causes page `PostBack` in `Page_Load` event.

Comment: Can anybody tell me any other way or it is only solution.

Comment: Why do you need to know this at `Page_Load` time?

Comment: Usually people ask this when they try to add web server controls to their pages dynamically, but are unable to make it right. If this is your case, I suggest you give a look at the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this you can try

```
string ctr = Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
```

Here `ctr` will contain your controls's `ID`.

`__EVENTTARGET` carry information who causes page `PostBack`

You can also use `__EVENTARGUMENT` to get argument pass by this control.

```
Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT")
```

Comment: Is there only way or we can do something else?